# WPF DataGrid: modify all selected items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to take all rows that are selected and modify one column value in each of them.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRowView DRV in ItemDataGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    DRV.Row.BeginEdit();
    DRV.Row.ItemArray[6] = true;
    DRV.Row.EndEdit();
}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try and edit the DataGridRow. Modify the objects bound to the grid instead. Then make a call to NotifyPropertyChanged that the collection the DataGrid is bound to has been updated.

Comment: I have a dataset bound to the grid so I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Got It.  If anyone is wondering how to do this, this article helped me.  Thanks Chris.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc%28VS.80%29.aspx